# Do I need to worry about this JBoss Wildfly EJB Debug message?

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.1

I'm new to EJB @Jboss WildFly. I have followed some tutorials and things seem to work. Though I get periodically the following debug message:

```
Send recover request for transaction origin node identifier 1 to EJB receiver with node name [compuntername]
```

Should I care about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the [JBoss documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/jbosstm/4.17.3.Final/guides/failure_recovery_guide/):

> The XARecoveryModule will use the XAResourceRecovery implementation to get a XAResource to the target datasource. On each invocation of periodicWorkSecondPass, the recovery module will issue an XAResource.recover request – this will (as described in the XA specification) return a list of the transaction identifiers (Xid’s) that are known to the datasource and are in an indeterminate (in-doubt) state. The list of these in-doubt Xid’s received on successive passes (i.e. periodicWorkSecondPass-es) is compared. Any Xid that appears in both lists, and for which no JTA ResourceRecord was found by the intervening transaction-initiated recovery is assumed to belong to a transaction that was involved in a crash before any JTA ResourceRecord was written, and a rollback is issued for that transaction on the XAResource.

In short, this message is generated for transaction recovery in case anything (database connection, network connection, server overload, etc) fails. If this is happening every now and then for you, then you should check what exactly is failing and take appropriate action. If this is once a while, then no need to worry.

More details can be found [here](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/RemoteEJBDistributedTransactionsAndRecovery).

Comment: I am getting same issue in my application that is running on wildfly 10 and jdk 1.8. How can I get exact reason for this issue.

Comment: Hi @sampada can you please give some advice to debug this kind of issue.

Comment: Have you checked this link - https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/RemoteEJBDistributedTransactionsAndRecovery ?

Comment: Yes, checked that link.